# Regex string that copy from one link to another

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, string, hyperlink

I have two links on page. I need jquery or pure JS script to do this on page load:

Find  this `docs/ANY VALUE/` from first link

and copy `ANY VALUE` to second link

```
<a href="http://domain.com/docs/ANY VALUE/">Link 1</a>
<a href="http://domain.com/images/ANY VALUE GOES HERE/">Link 2</a>
```

Comment: You don't need a regex for that. Give the first link an id, select that element by id, get the href attribute, get the ANY VALUE (e.g. by using split()) then select the second link and append the extracted value to the links href attribut.

Comment: Is it really any value? Including the slash, backslash, pipe, brackets? Or is it that you mean any url-legal character except slash?

Comment: any value is actually something like this 7FJ610H38WE2   only digits and uppercase letters

Comment: When do you need it by, and what is the salary?

Answer (score 0):

```
<a href="http://domain.com/docs/ANY VALUE/" id='link1'>Link 1</a>
<a href="http://domain.com/images/ANY VALUE GOES HERE/" id='link2'>Link 2</a>
```

Add `id`s for both the links, like above. And use this JQuery snippet

```
ANY_VALUE = $('#link1').attr('href').split('docs/')[1]

$('#link2').attr('href','http://domain.com/images/'+ANY_VALUE)
```

Comment: If i could not give id for first link cause it is  parsed from db as tag and i could not add on every record manually..   is there solution for this ?

Comment: At the time of parsing each link, can you add an ID to it? How many such links are there?

Comment: thousands links, i am not sure if i can add ID

Comment: These links appear adjacent?

Comment: they added and after that from DB they are parsed through tag.
You mean in db or in html source?
Only first link is parsed.

Comment: Is there any way you can know which `docs` link element corresponds to which `images` link element? What are you getting from the DB, can you post that too in the question?

Comment: I found this, can be adjusted to manipulate my links?
 http://jsfiddle.net/entropo/tkP74/

Comment: Is there any way you can know which docs link element corresponds to which images link element?

Comment: i don't know, but for me regex could do the job